# Why is this insertion query failing?

Tags: php, sql

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO `LMS`.`Presentation` 
    ('Pre_Name' ,'Path' ,'PLec_ID' ,'pdatein' ,'pdesc','PSems_ID') 
values 
    ('$fname','$newname','$com',NOW(),'$filedesc','$semes')"
) or die("failed");
```

Dear All,
I have a table named presentation and I am going to enter value to it, it is mentionable that $com and $sems are comboboxs value, but the query show failed, anyone could help please,
thanks in advance

Comment: Really better use prepared statements, against [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) hacks, and escaping `'` etcetera.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Answer (score 4):

You're using quotes when you should be using backticks:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `LMS`.`Presentation` (`Pre_Name`, `Path`, ...
```

Or simply don't use any special character. The backtick is only *necessary* if you do something silly like use a reserved word as a column name and I would hope people would choose their column names to be more readable.

In other words, `date` and `in` and `select` are silly names for columns, you should be using `expiry_date`, `isInLocation` and `selectionStatus`.

Comment: Totally missed the obvious. +1 for quick eyeballs :)

Comment: @Fluffeh, things are rarely obvious _before_ you see them. Hindsight is 80/20 vision :-)

Answer (score 1):

change `or die("failed")` into `or die(mysql_error())` and you'll know why.

btw, consider changing from **mysql** functions to **mysqli** functions. And use parameterized queries. Otherwise you will be open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("

INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, column3, column4 .... columnX)
VALUES(column1Data,column2Data, column3Data, column4Data ... columnXdata)

") or die(mysql_error());
```

- > rove on this example and if there isnt a alias for a table then could not use a alias.
- everything hiddends on details..